# Is it possible to have Publisher (Manufacturer) of installation (MSI) be dynamic according to property

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

When we deploy our products using OEM we have a requirement that our company name will not appear in the Publisher property of the installation in the add remove / other.
although we have easy way of choosing neutral name for the publisher we would love to be able to set the name dynamic according to property for the installation (and allow our partner to add his name to it)

1. Is it possible?
2. Will that impact the sign of the MSI?

Trying to add [PROPERYNAME] to the Manufacturer property in WIX 3 didn't work as it simply set the name to include the "[PROPERTYNAME]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the MSI would invalidate the signature, and since Manufacturer is a private property, it cannot be passed in from the command line. What can work is a transform, and the transform can be signed by the vendor so it doesn't harm the aggregate signature status on Windows 7 (MSI 5.0) and up. However applying the transform also requires a command line, so that may or may not be easy, depending on your bootstrap.